# Cellular map on a sub CW-complex defines CW-structure on the pushout of CW-complexs

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, cw-complexes

I want to show that given a subcomplex $A$ of a CW-complex say $X$ and a cellular map $f\colon A \to Y$ where $Y$ is another CW complex, the pushout $X\cup_A Y$ inherits CW-structure. I have an idea on how I would go about this but I am finding it difficult to put them together.

First of all, its natural to let the $n$-th skleton to be $X_n \cup_{A_n} Y_n$ and that a I believe it holds that
$$
X \cup_A Y = \bigcup_{n\geq-1} X_n \cup_{A_n} Y_n.
$$
The reason I believe this holds is that  think pushout is preserved under taking unions assuming compatibility(if they agree on the intersections?) of the pushouts. In the case of disjoint unions, I think this is immediate. I would like to know if this is actually the reason.

Secondly I want to show that $X_n\cup_{A_n}Y_n$ is obtained from $X_{n-1}\cup_{A_{n-1}}Y_{n-1}$ by attaching cells. If my intuitions are correct, this consists of $n$-cells in $Y_n$ and the $n$-cells in $X_n$ that are not in $A$. Therefore, I want to construct a pushout square
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
I_n\times \partial D^n \amalg J_n\times\partial D^n @>{q\circ x\amalg y}>> X_{n-1}\cup_{A_{n-1}}Y_{n-1}\\
@VVV @VVV \\
I_n\times  D^n \amalg J_n\times D^n @>{}>> X_{n}\cup_{A_{n}}Y_{n}
\end{CD}$$
where $q\circ x \amalg y$ is first the component-wise attaching map for $X_n\setminus A$ and $Y$ and then the restriction of the quotient to the pushout $X_n\cup_{A_{n}} Y_n$. But I have no idea how to show that this is a pushout square. Any help is appreciated

Comment: See 4.14 Theorem of this note https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kriegl/Skripten/2011WS.pdf or theorem 6.1.13 of this book https://www.google.co.in/books/edition/Lectures_on_Homotopy_Theory/h42R884Nn4AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=Theorem+6.1.13+Lectures+onHomotopy+TheoryR.A.+PICCININI&pg=PA168&printsec=frontcover